# How do I get the font of my signature to match the font of my message in Thunderbird?

Tags: email, fonts, thunderbird, email-signature

My message body and signature do not have the same font:

[image]

How do I find out what the "Fixed Width" font is so that I can match it with my signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Monospaced font (fixed-width)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font). In Thunderbird **Tools** (Alt + T) > **Options** > **Display** > **Formatting** > **Advanced** : `Sans-serif` and `Monospace` have to be the same. Please note that some fonts may not display correctly in the two modes.

[Variable width](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_width_font#Width), [Font settings](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Font_settings_in_Thunderbird), [Thunderbird Howtos](https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/category/20)